# ¿Cómo puedo unir 2 registros en una sola agrupación de un group by?

Tags: mysql

Cómo puedo hacer para que el registro que está nulo y el que está en blanco se cuenten como uno solo?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo que podrías hacer cambiar el valor en blanco a NULL o viceversa y al realizar la consulta ya estaría en un solo grupo.

Answer (score 1):

Después de pedir apoyo en diferentes grupos, me compartieron la solución y la publico para que esté al alcance de todos.

La solución estaba en group by.

```
SELECT CASE typehousing when '' then null else typehousing end as typehousing, count(*) count
FROM employees
GROUP BY CASE typehousing when '' then null else typehousing end
```